# How to return a value within a subfunction?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I want to return the first function as soon as I find the element.

This is just an example:

```js
function foo(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (e) {
      if (e == 4)
        return true // this obviously does not return the foo function
    });
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because we have fancy functions like `forEach`, it doesn't mean you can't still use plain `for` loops when you need them:

```
function foo(arr) {
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if (arr[x] == 4)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `return arr[x] == 4;` is also nice to see.

Comment: @Jai that would return false as soon as it sees an element that doesn't match, rather than checking them all?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> `some()` executes the `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a true value. If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns `true`. Otherwise, `some()` returns `false`. `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```js
function foo(arr) {
    return arr.some(function (e) {
        return e == 4;
    });
}

document.write(foo([1, 2, 3, 4]) + '<br>');
document.write(foo([1, 2, 3, 42]) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set up a variable in the scope of the `foo` function if you don't want to simply go for an old-school `for`.

```
function foo(arr) {
    var result = false;
    arr.forEach(function (e) {
      if (e == 4)
        result = true;
    });
    return result
}
```

Comment: OP did say "as soon as I find the element" - this will loop through them all.

Comment: Uh, I was on mobile, did not really see that :)